# How to fix SSIS Script task Invocation Error in SQL server agent job?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-agent-job

I have SSIS package with a script task to access excel files. When I deploy the package to SQL Server 2014 and run manually from SSIS Catalog its working fine.

But when I run the same package after creating a job, it fails with below error

[image]

Please suggest an FIX

Comment: You should add `try...catch(exception e)...` blocks to your Script task and push the error message via `FireWarning` to the message output - this helps in narrowing down the reason. On first glance I would say it's some user restriction or something, but this can only be told for sure if we have the error message

Comment: While running locally it is working fine.
Problem is when I try to run the package through SQL Server agent.

Comment: Yes, I understood the point. But how is your Job configured? Are you using the same credentials as execution user? However, adding the try-catch is still the thing to do - you can see the message output in the SSIS Execution Report, so you will see WHAT exactly is the problrem in the script task.

Comment: I have given access to network user as Full control.But still SQL Server Agent is not able to create or modify files in a folder.

Comment: Given the project name, Py1toXLSX, I assume you're using python so you can also factor in the path to the python.exe/python3.exe executable into the mix but yes, as Tyron78 indicates, it smells strongly of permissions

Comment: I am converting PY1(xml) file format to XLSX.

Comment: @Tyron78 's point is that is the error every script task throws and can mean anything.